# Incomplete Implementation Errror

Tags: objective-c

Keep getting a error on the last line @implementation line saying implementation incomplete. Not sure what the problem is. What would cause this? I posted the header too.

Added the rest of the code from the .m file.

```
    #import "mmViewController.h"

@interface mmViewController ()
-(void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer;

@end

@implementation mmViewController
@synthesize remainingTime, playerScore, scrambledWord;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //Initialize the game model
    gameModel = [[mmScramblerModel alloc] init];

    //Display the time, score and scrambled word
    remainingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.time];
    playerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.score];
    scrambledWord.text = [gameModel getScrambledWord];

    //Start the game timer
    gameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
}

-(void) endGameWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
    //Call this method to end the game

    //Invalidate the timer
    [gameTimer invalidate];

    //Show an alert with the results
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Over!"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

-(void) timerFired:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    //The timer fires this method rougly every second
    [gameModel timerTick];

    if(gameModel.time <= 0){
        remainingTime.text = 0;
        [self endGameWithMessage:@"You are out of time. You lose!"];
    }
    else
        remainingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameModel.time];
}

@end








#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "mmScramblerModel.h"

@interface mmViewController : UIViewController {
    mmScramblerModel* gameModel;
    NSTimer* gameTimer;
}
-(IBAction)guessTap:(id)sender;
-(void) endGameWithMessage:(NSString*) message;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField * guessText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * scrambledWord;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * remainingTime;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * playerScore;

@end
```

Comment: Did you implement the two methods shown in your interface? Did you implement the `timerFired` method in your class extension? BTW - get rid of the `@synthesize` lines. Those aren't needed anymore. And there is no need for the method declaration in the class extension either.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the methods listed in the .h file. Now look at the methods that you actually implemented. SInce there are only two, it's pretty easy to notice that you didn't implement one of them.

Implement the `guessTap:` method.

Answer (score 0):

From your code i can see the `interface declaration` of

`-(IBAction)guessTap:(id)sender;`

But you have not implemented this method in `.m` file

Answer (score 0):

remove the `guessTap:` method from interface